# Contact form not sending dropdown value to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, drop-down-menu

I'm putting together a contact form that leverages a drop down field for limit the selection choices for the user.  The generated email works perfectly, except for the drop down field.  Observing the console the field is pulled correctly but it doesn't populate in the PHP form (e.g. "$("select#commMethod").val();" returns whatever is selected).  Emails keep coming through with "undefined" in place of communication method.  I know there are several posts about forms not being named, methods not being used, inputs not having value flags, however I have all those in place.  Any pointers in the right direction are appreciated.  This is all pretty new to me so apologize if I'm asking a simple question.

HTML (abbreviated)

```
 <form name="sentMessage" id="teleForm" novalidate method="post">
        <div class="row mb-3">
          <div class="col-lg-5">
            <H2>Contact Info</H2>
            <hr>
            <!--name-->
            <div class="control-group">
              <div class="form-group col-md-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                <legend>Full Name</legend>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullname" required
                  data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--phone-->
            <div class="control-group">
              <div class="form-group col-md-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                <legend>Phone Number</legend>
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" required
                  data-validation-required-message="Please enter a valid phone number.">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--communication option-->
            <filedset class="form-group">
              <div class="form-group col-md-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                <legend>Preferred Communication platform</legend>
                <select id="commMethod" name="commMethod">
                  <option value="GoogleDuo">Google Duo</option>
                  <option value="Facebook Messenger">Facebook Messenger</option>
                  <option value="Other">Other - Input in message</option>
                </select>
              </div>
        <div id="success"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <!--submit button-->
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="sendMessageButton-tele">Request</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

JS code (abbreviated)

```
    submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
  // get values from FORM
  var name = $("input#fullname").val();
  var email = $("input#email").val();
  var phone = $("input#phone").val();
  var message = $("textarea#message").val();
  var prefComm = $("select#commMethod").val();
  var commID = $("input#userid").val();
  var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
  // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
  if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
    firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
  }
  $this = $("#sendMessageButton-tele");
  $this.prop("disabled", true); // Disable submit button until AJAX call is complete to prevent duplicate messages
  $.ajax({
    url: "././mail/contact_me_consult.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      name: name,
      phone: phone,
      email: email,
      commmethod: prefComm,
      message: commID + " - " + message 
    },
```

PHP

```
    <?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])      ||
   empty($_POST['email'])     ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])     ||
   empty($_POST['message'])   ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
   echo "No arguments Provided!";
   return false;
   }

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$commmethod = ($_POST['commmethod']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'xxxx@xxx.com';
$email_subject = "Consult Tele Request:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\ncommunication method:$commmethod\n\nMessage: $message";
$headers = "From: noreply@xxxxxxx.com\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";   
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;         
?>
```

Comment: `$commmethod = ($_POST['commmethod']));` <- there is one too many parentheses here (though actually, you don't need any at all if you're just grabbing the post value as is). Are you sure that's the code you have right now? This should result in a parse error.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, suddenly started working, possibly a hosting issue. Thanks anyway.